# How do you "slur" two of the same notes?

Tags: piano, notation, composition

If I had two Cs that were half notes right next to each other, and I wanted to hold the first one for two counts, then immediately play the second one after releasing the key for a fraction of a second, how would I notate that?

Comment: Why not just two plain notes? The assumption is that notes will be played full length, with just enough break to clarify them as separate. This seems exactly what you want?

Comment: Just mark the section 'legato'.
Def. "in a smooth, flowing manner, without breaks between notes."
Do not take the definition too literally when applied to the same pitch; in that case legato means to make the breaks as short as possible and not to accent the notes.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what instrument you're writing for.  Since you selected 'piano' as one of your tags, I assume that's what you want to write for.  There are a couple of ways to notate this.  The way I'm most familiar with is to put a tenuto mark over each note (looks like a hyphen) and then a slur over that.  (Or under and under, if the stems are up.)  Be sure NOT to put a tie, but a slur.  They look very similar but not identical.